# Choose the Most Dramatic Outcome

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, probability-theory

The premise of this is simple: [A 10% chance is pretty unlikely, but everyone knows that a one-in-a-million chance is a sure thing!](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0584.html)

So, write code that implements the following "dramatic" probability rules:

- Take in a floating point *P* from 0 to 1 representing the unmodified chance of some plot-related event, and a boolean representing whether we're in the climax or not.
- Determine *P'* on these conditions:

  - If 0 < *P* ≤ 10<sup>-3</sup> then *P'* = 1.
  - If .999 ≤ *P* < 1 then *P'* = 0.
  - If *P* = 0 and we're in the climax, then the heroes will likely get a last-minute sudden advantage and *P'* = .9.
  - If *P* = 1 and we're in the climax, then the villain will unveil an as-yet-unseen superweapon and *P'* = .1.
  - Otherwise, *P'* = *P*.
- Return truthy or falsey based on *P'* as the chance of truth. For example, if *P'* = .7, then you should return truthy 70% of the time and falsey 30% of the time.

Shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: See also [Million-to-one chance](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Million-to-one_chance) [quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Discworld#Mort_%281987%29).

Comment: @Neil Discworld has literal Random Number Gods?

Comment: Discworld has all possible Gods, but only the ones that get believed in have any power.

Comment: Alternative title: "Does your language have a terse if-else ternary operator?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands),  <s>44</s>  42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

<sup>[Crossed out &nbsp;44&nbsp; is no longer 44 :)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)</sup>

```
_i90*ë¹₄*©1›i1₄®-‹i¹т*ë¹iiTëтë0ëт]5°<Ý₄/Ω›
```

Port of [my Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174717/52210).
First input is `P`, second input is `0`/`1` for truthy/falsey whether there is a climax.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/PtPSQOvw6kM7HzW1aB1aafioYVemIZB9aJ3uo4admYd2XmwCS2dmhhxefbHp8GoDEBVremiDzeG5QHX651YCtfz/b6BnymUAAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
_i                     # If the first (implicit) input is exactly 0:
  90                   #  Push 90
    *                  #  Multiply it with the second (implicit) input (0 if 0, 90 if 1)
 ë                     # Else:
  ¹₄*                  #  Push the first input, and multiply it by 1000
     ©                 #  Save it in the register (without popping)
      1›i              #  If it's larger than 1 (so input larger than 0.001):
          ₄®-          #   Push 1000, and subtract the value from the register
         1   ‹i        #   If it's smaller than 1 (so input smaller than 0.999):
               ¹т*     #    Push the first input multiplied by 100
              ë        #   Else:
               ¹i      #    If the first input is exactly 1:
                 i     #     If the second (implicit) input is 1:
                  T    #      Push 10
                 ë     #     Else:
                  т    #      Push 100
                ë      #    Else:
                 0     #     Push 0
          ë            #  Else:
           т           #   Push 100
   ]                   # Close all if-else clauses
    5°                 # Push 100000 (10**5)
      <                # Decrease it by 1: 99999
       Ý               # Create a list in the range [0,99999]
        ₄/             # Divide it by 1000: [0,0.001,0.002,...,99.997,99.998,99.999]
          Ω            # Take a random value from the list
           ›           # Check if the earlier value is larger than this random value
                       # (and output implicitly)
```

05AB1E has no builtin for a random decimal value in the range `[0, 1)`, so I use `5°<Ý₄/` to generate a list in the range `[0,99.999]` in steps of `0.001` and then `Ω` to take a random value from that list (and I use percentages `[0, 100]` instead of decimals `[0, 1]` in the rest of my code).

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 86 bytes

```r
function(a,b,d=a*(1-a))runif(1)<="if"(d,"if"(d>999e-6,a,1-round(a)),"if"(b,.9-.8*a,a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/RCoMwDEXf9xXiUyJpacc2VtD9S9QWCluVYr@/6/R5NS8Xcm4OJGbX9KLJLoVp80sAppHmgTvQghFjCt6Bxn5ovWthpiNexhgrHsSkRVxSmKF0DzaSNEI@O6ayyh/LAaJd337izYJWZagISSPi5Q9VVSpvV1InvHpf4l437I2qo/x/4tgbP0f@Ag)

`a` is P' and `b` is 1 or 0 for "in the climax" or not.

If `a` is 0 or 1, then `d` will be 0, in which case if `b` is 0 just return `a`, otherwise `.9` minus `.8*a`.

Otherwise if `a` is not near 0 or 1, d will be "far" from 0 so return `a`. Otherwise `1-round(a)` will take `a` to the "opposite" 0 or 1.

Then see if a random selection from `[0,1]` is less than or equal to the resulting probability.

The link does a little simulation for all the possible scenarios to demonstrate that it all seems to work.

Comment: Where did you get the `999e-6` from?

Comment: Since `0 <= a <= 1`, `d` will be bigger than `999e-6 = 0.000999` exactly when `a < 0.001` or `a  > 0.999`.

Comment: Huh, I was wondering how you could take advantage of the symmetry in the sandbox, you seem to have figured it out.

Comment: Also, you can save bytes on parentheses by setting `d` to `a-a*a`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

Zero bytes of source code. Use the preprocessor directive:

```c
-Df(p,c)=rand()<~(1<<31)*(c&p==0?.9:p==1&c?.1:(p<=1e-3|p>=.999)&p!=1&p!=0?p<.1:p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBdS8MwFIav119xNkmbU9qSUHbRmlgQb7zRMbwUpKTNCKwhdAMFP366MU4mut7s5hx43vd8qnyjlPf@ouu1sT2s1rd3D0@r9f01dSOCG43da7ogy4JrQmogCkj3aBcZcMYghW9XBmprhvYFGkjSBGpIIMlAB@moIEZDayzF12i2G1vb0b0ZesoQL6NZmHBsIIEF8GcHVpR4SviEMDZlVVVNfSeE/5Df4fzMgn/kLPDuP5Xetpudz599fhN@kymUh0@g@KBciJJjSlXspGRNUdUh81g1Ba@pE5L3efnmruThqtjNgxYCa5wIBodf)

Very little to explain about it; `p` is the probability, `c` the climax boolean. Main golfing trick is `~(1<<31)`, which seems to be the equivalent to `RAND_MAX` for gcc. The usual C golfing tricks go straight out the window with floating points.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 65 bytes

```java
P->C->Math.random()<(P==0?C?.9:0:P>.001?P<.999?P:P==1?C?.1:1:0:1)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZPNasJAEMfveYpBaMlqXHcFkaiJ0JTeCgserYdVY42NiZiNIMVrH6CP2Bexkw814mpOm/n/ZmbnY1dyJ5ur@ddxFsokgXcZRN8GQKKkCmawQpWmKgjpIo1mKogj@lYeBq9xOg196yHzEsehLyMLyoPrwgKco2i6XtN9l2pJtzKax2uTDEzhOGzoDandYz3hUsb4UAyobdtD0UONZxrvcVQ5OfYNo1U3hMMs8JyFDBN/D9Xv7@cXOGNPUGgnUm1TtbwlbQQLqY9eFSeTWSy7ySRz9gO19LfX4QuvnMw4pPHCpEJnpCnqCJNLDhN/myfjOdk4d7Y4uZfsTPIHtfBKLfaN06NWlbXUWwYuwAaHiwtQ7sEuDuawxt0wR2obRJ/jCUiS7QmA8hOFbSrykP6VDSNem7BHrKNjS0HnwO/wXIe39dHb2th6Vot29WxXC2dT1NG5XYt37vGa@Lp@VHtxMC7vN59bTszz1wrCgmnxFMErBzjaJ8pf0zhVdIOzVWFkikYNnqHW8Bq1D1VrLKjcbMK9KUh58EiZ6XD8Bw)

**Explanation:**

We have the following scenario combinations to consider:

```java
P=0, C=falsey             → 100% falsey
P=0, C=truthy             → 90% truthy; 10% falsey
P=(0,0.001], C=either     → 100% truthy
P=(0.001,0.999), C=either → (P*100)% truthy; (100-P*100)% falsey
P=[0.999,1), C=either     → 100% falsey
P=1, C=truthy             → 10% truthy; 90% falsey
P=1, C=falsey             → 100% truthy
```

Which gives us the following code:

```java
P->C->           // Method with double and boolean parameters and boolean return-type
  Math.random()  //  Random value in the range [0, 1)
   <(P==0?       //  If P is 0:
      C?         //   And there is a climax:
       .9        //    Check if the random value is smaller than 0.9 (90% true)
      :          //   Else:
       0         //    Check if the random value is smaller than 0 (0% true)
    :P>.001?     //  Else-if P is larger than 0.001:
      P<.999?    //   If P is smaller than 0.999, so in range (0.001,0.999):
       P         //    Check if the random value is smaller than P (P*100% true)
      :P==1?     //   Else-if P is 1:
       C?        //    And there is a climax:
        .1       //     Check if the random value is smaller than 0.1 (10% true)
       :         //    Else:
        1        //     Check if the random value is smaller than 1 (100% true)
      :          //   Else, so P is in the range [0.999,1):
       0         //    Check if the random value is smaller than 0 (0% true)
    :            //  Else, so P is in the range (0,0.001]:
     1)          //   Check if the random value is smaller than 1 (100% true)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 54 bytes

```perl6
{(($/=1-$^p min$p)??.001>=$/||$/!!$^c*.9)>rand^^$p>.5}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsIwFET3/YpbuEgiMQ8hYpAkf5JS1IBga4irYv32mLZu5gyHYdI9P09lmGAXwZYPISisOmBIMDxGTNR7LqVyFsU8o2hbDNc9N9TlfryFgMlx/S3vfgKCHQMfiWSAHV2rWiuF@MpN1bI@Sb1RbTiyRnK9hDHnRRlj/qhDdSk/)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{
 (
  ($/=1-$^p min$p)    # Compute min(p,1-p) and store in $/
  ??                  # if $/ > 0
    .001>=$/||        #   if $/ <= 0.001 then 1
    $/                #   else $/
  !!$^c*.9            # else 0.9 * climax
 )>rand               # Random Bool with given probability
 ^^$p>.5              # Flip if p > 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 61 bytes

```perl
$_=(!$_?<>?.9:0:$_==1?<>?.1:1:$_<=.001||($_<.999&&$_))>rand<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZDUSXe3sbOXs/SysAKyLc1BPMMrQyBPBtbPQMDw5oaDSBTz9LSUk1NJV5T064oMS/Fxu7/f0Muw3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcgA)

Input is on two lines.  First line is P; second line is 0 if not in climax, 1 if in climax.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 118 bytes

```
from random import *
def f(p,c):
if c:
 if p==1:p=.9
 if p==0:p=.1
if p<1e-3:p=1
if p>.999:p=0
return random()<p
```

Inputs: p is initial probability, c is climax