# Generate a Baseball Pitch String

Tags: code-golf, sequence, random

## Goal

Write a program or function that takes a positive integer `n` and randomly generate a legal series of pitches (henceforth called a Pitch string) of length `n`.

## Input

A non-zero, positive integer `n` <= 100

## Output

Return a random string, or list of characters, that represent a possible, valid pitch string of length `n`. The characters used will be:

- **B** - Ball. If you accumulate 4 of these, the batter is walked and finished batting.
- **S** - Strike. If you accumulate 3 of these, the batter is out and finished batting.
- **F** - Foul. Will also increase the Strike count but cannot get the batter out. I.e., you cannot have a Foul be the last pitch in a valid string. Any fouls past two strikes/fouls will not increase the Strike count (the batter already has 2 strikes at that point and a 3rd would get him out).
- **H** - Hit. The batter has hit a ball into play and is finished batting.

(This is simplified slightly but don't you worry about that)

Valid pitch strings are those that end in a strike-out, a walk, or a hit.

I.e., an **invalid** pitch string has either

- additional pitches after the 4th Ball, 3rd Strike, or Hit
- terminated before generating a 4th ball, 3rd strike, or Hit.

## Rules

- Your program must be able to produce all possible results for a given input.
- Your program does not have to be uniformly random but still must follow the previous rule.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

## Examples

```
Input => Possible Outputs
1 => [H] #Can only end with a hit
2 => [S,H], [B,H], [F,H] #Can only end with a hit
3 => [S,S,S], [F,F,S], [B,B,H], ... #Can now strike-out, otherwise must end with a hit
4 => [B,B,B,B], [S,B,S,S], [B,F,S,S], [B,B,B,H], ... #Can now be walked, struck-out, or get a hit
6 => [S,B,S,B,B,H], [F,F,F,F,F,S], ... #Can now have a full-count (3 balls, 2 strikes) before finishing 

Input => Invalid Outputs
1 => [S], [B]    #Not enough for a strike-out/walk
2 => [S,S]       #Not enough for a strike-out/walk
2 => [H,H]       #Batter has already scored a hit
3 => [S,S,F]     #Fouls will not cause a strike-out
4 => [S,S,S,H]   #Batter has already struck out
5 => [B,B,B,B,B] #Batter has already walked
```

Comment: So we have to be able to produce anywhere from 1 to infinity F's?

Comment: The string will be at most 100 characters long. Fouls are what allows such long pitching strings, e.g. 99 `F`s and a `S` is a strike-out

Comment: Oh, got it, missed that

Comment: @Quintec Reworded it to be a bit more explicit just in case

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 128 bytes

```python
from random import*
def g(n):
 x=i=S=0;r=''
 while(S>2)+x<3>=i-S:x=randint(0,3);r+='BFSH'[x];S+=x>0;i+=1
 return(i==n)*r or g(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY47D4IwFIV3fsXdaCkmPOIg9TI4GPeOhBgTCjSRC7nBWH89Uienc4bvPJbPOs5UbFvP8wT8oG4XNy0zr0nU2R4GQbKKwKNDg5lmjOMI3qN7WmHqQip/Lmt0B1N5DGlHq8jSUmpWGF@u5hY3vtVGoa8z7RTmEbBdX0zCIZJMGGb@bWz9bggchRODFXl6CrsL741AaRMYCMz9jznKdvsC)

Randomly generate the pitch string until the batter is done, output it if it turns out the right length, and otherwise try again from scratch.

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 136 bytes**

```python
from random import*
def g(n):
 B=H=F=S=0;r=''
 while(F+S<3or'S'>x)>B/4+H:x=choice('BHFS');r+=x;exec x+"+=1"
 return(len(r)==n)*r or g(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69DoIwFEZ3nuLGpa0lUfwZBC8DA2FnNMYYKNAEbskNxvr0CE5O3xlOcr7xM3WODvPcsBuAn1QvY4fR8bQNatNAK0nFAWRYYI4l7hNGIQJ4d7Y3Mtfl9ehYlCL1Ks12J13EHqvO2cpIkRV5KVTCGn1ivKnA643GaBMAm@nFJHtDkhUiqS2D419rbhYgsLSeaY2MwsvaH9nSBBTeVgdW5/HnnNV9/gI)

Comment: Kevin's port of this made me realize this breaks down for higher numbers. `n=8` can generate a chain of `F`s at the end

Comment: @Veskah Nice catch. I hadn't accounted for the strike count (counting fouls) possibly going up to 6, and changing `S/3` to `(S>2)` fixes it.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands),  <s>44</s>  <s>50</s> 44 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

[<sup>*Crossed out `&nbsp;44&nbsp;` is no longer 44 :)*</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)

```
[õ0U.µ["BFSH"3ÝΩ©è«®ĀX+U¼X2›®+3@¾X-3›~#}I¾Q#
```

Port of [*@xnor*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180491/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well if you like this answer!
+6 bytes due to a bug-fix, and after that -6 bytes again thanks to *@xnor* by porting his way more efficient fix in comparison to my temporary work-around, as I was expecting. ;)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUgAt/9vc2FiaWX//1vDtTBVLsK1WyJCRlNIIjPDnc6pwqnDqMKrwq7EgFgrVcK8WDLigLrCriszQMK@WC0z4oC6fiN9ScK@USP//zk) or [verify some more random outputs](https://tio.run/##AV4Aof9vc2FiaWX/OUx2IlNpemU6ICI/eSwxMEb/W8O1MFUuwrVbIkJGU0giM8OdzqnCqcOowqvCrsSAWCtVwrxYMuKAusKuKzNAwr5YLTPigLp@I315wr5RI/99LH3Ctj//).

**Explanation:**

```python
[                # Start an infinite loop:
 õ               #  (Re)set the result-string to an empty string ""
 0U              #  (Re)set variable `X` to 0
 .µ              #  Reset the counter_variable to 0
   [             #  Start an inner infinite loop:
    "BFSH"       #   Push string "BFSH"
          3ÝΩ    #   Push a random integer in the range [0,3]
             ©   #   Store this random integer in variable `r` (without popping)
              è  #   Index it into the string "BFSH"
               « #   Append it to the result-string
    ®Ā           #   If `r` is NOT 0:
      X+U        #    Increase `X` by 1
    ¼            #   Increase the counter_variable by 1
    X2›®+        #   Calculate `X`>2 (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey) + `r`
         3@      #   Check if this is larger than or equal to 3
    ¾X-          #   Calculate counter_variable - `X`
       3›        #   Check if this is larger than 3
    ~            #   If either of the two checks above is truhy:
     #           #    Stop the inner infinite loop
   }             #  After the inner infinite loop:
    I¾Q          #  If the input and counter_variable are equal:
       #         #   Stop the outer infinite loop
                 # (and output the result-string at the top of the stack implicitly)
```

Comment: @Veskah I've done a straight-forward fix for now. I have the feeling _xnor_ is able to do a shorter fix, so I'll probably port his fix to save some bytes later on. :)

Comment: You can fix it like I did by changing `X/3` to `X>2`.

Comment: @xnor Thanks, back to 44 bytes again. I knew you'd find something shorter. ;p

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 148 bytes

```r
function(n){`~`=paste0
`*`=sample
o=""
while(nchar(o)<n-1){a=c("B"[T<4],"F","S"[F<2])*1
F=F+(a>"E")
T=T+(a<"F")
o=o~a}
o~c("B"[T>3],"H","S"[F>1])*1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCoMwGATgPU9R/im/VWisY5Kh0NC9biIkiEHBJqKWDqKvnkZwOW6476ZgLzwL9uuapfeOOlz1rsVo5qW9EZ1oMZvPOLTECwDy6/qhpa7pzEQ9cpcxXI1oKDygKnlRp6AghTdUiuc1Jowooa7USHgCklKUsfM4wfjmd7MRv59W3qN9nVayw27BUobE0vyIAsMf)

Generates the string, using conditional inclusion in the sampling datasets to ensure that the result is a possible pitch sequence.

Possibly doing rejection sampling (as [xnor's python answer does](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180491/67312)) is shorter.

```r
function(n){`~`=paste0		# alias
`*`=sample			# alias
o=""				# empty string for output
while(nchar(o)<n-1){		# do n-1 times:
a=c("B"[T<4],"F","S"[F<2])*1	# sample 1 from the string "BFS", conditionally including B or S if the ball/strike count is 3/2	
F=F+(a>"E")			# increment F (strike count) if sampled character is F or S
T=T+(a<"F")			# increment T (ball count) if sampled character is B
o=o~a}				# append a to output

o~c("B"[T>3],"H","S"[F>1])*1}	# append the sampled "BHS", conditionally including B or S if the ball/strike count is 3/2.
```

Random ["F and S" reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDB97j8_HSk) that kept playing in my head every time I typed one of those letters...

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 137 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,o='',i=Math.random()*4|0,r=/^(?!.*((B.*){4}|([SF].*){2}S|H).)/)=>r.test(o)?n?f(n-1,o+'BSFH'[i%4])||i<8&&f(n,o,i+1):!r.test(o+1)&&o:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY2xTsMwEIZ3noIOTe5S95q0GVDBjehQdWHKGAXJoo4wEDuyTaHCffaQCLEiIfWfvjvdff@LOAr3ZFXn565TB2lbo1/lqe8bDpoZHsdM8Qfhn8kKfTAtYJKHlFm@eIRiQgnAlhL8ys8BqnJXj7w8l2GPhAvkG0teOg8GC100oOcZM7N4W@72caWmeY0hqLubKGrGLqZmGa4nvy/DEEVmnfadVdpDRURaflyX8ofvrRUnyNIhWFMrOvjkmwYyRKSjeHuXDoa9M9YD4tW/HMsLOFYXcOR/OZrxHvG2/wY)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 53 bytes

```
u+GO?H+W<K/G\B3+W<Jl@"SF"G2\F\S\B+WqK3+WgJ2\H\S\B_UQ[
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BGO%3FH%2BW%3CK%2FG%5CB3%2BW%3CJl%40%22SF%22G2%5CF%5CS%5CB%2BWqK3%2BWgJ2%5CH%5CS%5CB_UQ%5B&input=10&debug=0).

This feels way too long, I think another approach may be required.

```
u+GO?H+W<K/G\B3+W<Jl@"SF"G2\F\S\B+WqK3+WgJ2\H\S\B_UQ[   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
                                                 _UQ    Reversed range from Q-1 to 0
u                                                   [   Reduce the above, with initial value G=[], next value as H:
                    @"SF"G                                Keep elements of G which are in "SF"
                   l                                      Length of the above
                  J                                       Store in J - this is the number of strikes and fouls so far
          /G\B                                            Count number of "B"s in G
         K                                                Store in K - this is the number of balls so far
    ?H                                                    If H is not 0 (i.e. not final pitch):
                           \F                               Start with "F" (foul is always available in non-final pitch)
                W<J       2                                 If J<2...
               +             \S                             ... append "S"
       W<K    3                                             If K<3...
      +                        \B                           ... append "B"
                                                          Else:
                                           \H               Start with "H" (hit is always available in final pitch)
                                       WgJ2                 If J >= 2...
                                      +      \S             ... append "S"
                                  WqK3                      If K == 3...
                                 +             \B           ... append "B"
   O                                                      Choose one element at random from the available options
 +G                                                       Append the above to G
                                                        Implicit print the result of the reduce operation
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>107 106</s>  99 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=p=s=0,o='')=>p&&p>2|k-s>3|s>2&p<2?k-n?f(n):o:f(n,k+1,o+'FSBH'[p=Math.random()*4|0,s+=p<2,p])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xDoJAEER7v2IruPMOAqiN3EJiYWysLI0FQVFEdy@csRG/HY/Caibz8pK5V@/K1X1rXxHx@TKODQrSHVp0mGjGMJRY2CCwRTZ0kSsWgyuywJqs7CIqG0FyzetmUlSqWYXbw2YXHi3uq9ct7is681PI@XJItFPoNW1Pcmy4FwQIaQ4EBmHlUykJnxnAxFrPkhxaMJCCMUC@/zlAzeT4cYkffBXTAZn7@Tv7jj8)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                       // f = recursive function taking:
  n,                        //   n = requested length
  k =                       //   k = pitch counter, initialized to 0
  p =                       //   p = last pitch
  s = 0,                    //   s = sum of strikes and fouls
  o = ''                    //   o = output string
) =>                        //
  p &&                      // if the last pitch was not a foul
  p > 2 |                   // AND the last pitch was a hit
  k - s > 3 |               //     OR we have 4 balls (or 3 balls + 1 hit)
  s > 2 & p < 2 ?           //     OR more than 2 strikes or fouls, ending with a strike:
    k - n ?                 //   if k is not equal to n:
      f(n)                  //     valid series but bad timing: try again from scratch
    :                       //   else:
      o                     //     success: return o
  :                         // else:
    f(                      //   do a recursive call:
      n,                    //     n is unchanged
      k + 1,                //     increment k
      o + 'FSBH'            //     append the pitch letter to o
        [ p = Math.random() //     pick a new random pitch
              * 4 | 0,      //     in [0..3]
          s += p < 2,       //     increment s if the pitch is a foul or a strike
          p ]               //     actual index in 'FSBH'
    )                       //   end of recursive call
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>120</s> <s>119</s> <s>116</s> 117 bytes

```
=f(n)
->g(n,3,2)
=g(n,b,s)
~n--
{n:{~{b:b->g(n,b-1,s)}|{s:s->g(n,b,s-1)}|}f->g(n,b,s-(s>0))|{~{b:h|b}|{s:h|s}|h}}->->
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYsxDsMgDEV3n6IjlrAEzYaEp3bNIRgoqBJDPAK5OoW0Ujf7/fdyeQ/iQ1ljjL5tCOAPVXRGqMURR5WRuBE/90eHJRaycx0@qoITvKa86TuCX1fQgnAWolXXswYXvkqYlWBvVZz8iBayk/T4/5WwQWxXmFq49NSkt9Q7MfEYHw)

Probably still golfable.

## Ungolfed (mildly reformatted)

```
=f(length) // Define a stitch f, with one parameter which specifies the length of the created string. This is the intended entry point.
->g(length,3,2) // Instantly divert to g, defined below, with some extra parameters

=g(length,balls_left,strikes_left) // Define a stitch g, with three parameters.
~ length--                         // Decrement remaining length
{
    - length: // If this is not to be the last character in the string
              // randomly do one of the following:
              // 1. If balls_left is nonzero, print a b and recurse
              // 2. If strikes_left is nonzero, print an s and recurse
              // 3. Do nothing
              // If we did not divert earlier, print an f and recurse.
        {~{balls_left:b->g(length,balls_left-1,strikes_left)}|{strikes_left:s->g(length,balls_left,strikes_left-1)}|}f->g(length,balls_left,strikes_left-(strikes_left>0)) 
    - else: // Randomly do one of the following
            // 1. If a ball would result in a walk, print a b, otherwise an h.
            // 2. If a strike would result in a strikeout, print an s, otherwise an h.
            // 3. Just print an h.
            // And finally, halt.
        {~{balls_left:h|b}|{strikes_left:h|s}|h}}->->
```

**Edits**

1. Saved a byte by finishing with `->->` instead of `->END`.
2. Saved three bytes by decrementing `n` earlier.
3. Fixed a bug that caused strikeouts in incorrect places, thanks to @veskah for spotting it (+1 byte)

Comment: Based on the write-up and outputs, it looks like it doesn't factor in fouls incrementing the strike-count correctly

Comment: @veskah Well spotted, should be fixed now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 77 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{'HBSF'[{⍺←⍬⋄∨/((⊃⌽⍺)=⍳3)∧1,4 3≤(⊃s),+/1↓s←⍺∘(+/=)¨1+⍳3:⍺⋄∇⍨⍺,?4}⍣{i=≢⍺}i←⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rdwynYTT26@lHvrkdtEx71rnnU3fKoY4W@hsajruZHPXuB4pq2j3o3G2s@6lhuqGOiYPyocwlIrlhTR1vf8FHb5GKwvl2POmZoaOvbah5aYagNUm8FEgOZ1f6odwWQrWNvUvuod3F1pu2jzkVAfm0mWN/W2Nr/aWBW36O@qZ7@QJMPrTd@1DYRyAsOcgaSIR6ewf@BAmmHVhjrA002NAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 57 bytes

```
≔⁰η≔⁰ζＦ⊖Ｎ«≔‽⁺²‹ζ³ι¿›ι¹≦⊕ζ≦⊕η§SFB∨ι›η²»⊞υHＦ›η¹⊞υSＦ›ζ²⊞υB‽υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/LaoNAFIbX@hQHV0eYgpplVgmlrdCmkjzBRE/qgI4yl1IMffbJaDQJlC5/@P5bWXNVdrxxbqO1@JKYMKjjdXhXg1enTgE@U6moJWmowlz21uxseySFcRzDOQxmx57LqmuxaKzGjME7aY0Dg5WnGAifFYgT4KsibrxXMEi9/YP3sz2Xt5JrdUCNpv@AcWlQKCENbkwuK/rB6PCyjRh8TtlLTc0g8wM8/RsWVtdoGURv0fLsARvX3IjDH2KYgu7EdiSuA@bj1rc4lybu6bu5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰η≔⁰ζ
```

Start with 0 balls and 0 strikes.

```
Ｆ⊖Ｎ«
```

Loop over all of the deliveries except the last.

```
≔‽⁺²‹ζ³ι
```

If the have been fewer than three balls, then generate a random number from 0 to 2, otherwise just coinflip between 0 and 1.

```
¿›ι¹≦⊕ζ≦⊕η
```

A random value of 2 is a ball otherwise it increases the strike count.

```
§SFB∨ι›η²»
```

The values 0 to 2 map to strike, foul and ball, except that if there would be three strikes then foul is printed instead. (Four balls are excluded above.)

```
⊞υHＦ›η¹⊞υSＦ›ζ²⊞υB‽υ
```

Determine whether a strike or ball would get the batter out and choose from those or a hit as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC) <s>164</s> <s>145</s> 142 bytes

-3 bytes ceilingcat

```
#define A(a)!i&&!r--?puts(#a),++a,--n:0;
b,s,f,h,i,r;p(n){srand(time(0));for(i=n;i--;){for(n=1;n;){r=rand()&3;b>2^!A(b)s+f>1^!A(s)!A(f)A(h)}}}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HYrLCoMwEADvfkVEkF1MQO2tixZ/pBAfqXtwK4k9if31VHsZZmAG8xqGGLNxciyT6sBiynmeemMesH62AJlFXRRWGyN4LynpddBOz5q1pxUE9@CtjLDxMkGJSO7tgRuhrzFMuF8pTUVyum/@K@Y36tv6mXbQYyhcW10a8ITDDmY8jiOybGqxLIBqT5RaoaqRkiP@AA)

Comment: Suggest `&n` instead of `time(0)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 122 bytes

```perl
map{$B=$S=$H=0;while($B<4&&$S<3&&!$H&&/./g){${$&}++;$S+=$&eq F&&$S<2}y///c>pos||push@a,$_}glob"{B,F,H,S}"x<>;say$a[rand@a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBCoIwGADgVyn5@SlczkpPOhEP4qXTjhGxSlQwt1xRMvfqLeg7f6oe@9i5u1AGCgacQcXC5N12fb2CIo0Qgad7xCVUiDSgzdqAAbS@nwD3GWD9WJT/tLMTpfSaKannWb10mwsCZ9v08uKZgpSkItx6nzRLtJhAHEcx3HJxci76SvXs5KDd5hAH4Tb8AQ)

Comment: @Veskah  I missed that part.  Fixed it.