# Is this skew symmetry?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

In this challenge, your task is to detect (vertical) *Skewer Symmetry*. This means that one half of the pattern can be produced by mirroring the other half along a vertical axis, and then moving it vertically.

For example, the following pattern has skewer symmetry:

```
asdf    
jkl;fdsa
    ;lkj
```

Because if you start from the left half...

```
asdf               
jkl;
```

...then mirror it along a vertical axis...

```
    fdsa
    ;lkj
```

...then move it down by a character (filling the empty rows with spaces)...

```
    fdsa
    ;lkj
```

...you get the second half.

### Rules:

- You may assume the input is rectangle and has an even number of columns.
- If the pattern itself exhibits reflection symmetry, it is considered skewer symmetry.
- This is strict character by character symmetry, so `[[` is considered symmetrical, but not `[]`.
- You should output truthy if the input has skewer symmetry, falsy otherwise.
- Default I/O rules apply, standard loopholes are banned.

### Test Cases

Truthy cases:

```
asdf    
jkl;fdsa
    ;lkj
```

```
asdffdsa
```

```
[ 


 [
```

```
  ba
abdc
cd
```

Falsy cases:

```
[ 
 ]
```

```
ab
ba
```

```
aa
a 
 a
```

```
a  a
b b
```

```
ab  
  b 
   a
```

Comment: suggested test case: `["abfe","cdhg","efba","ghdc"]`. i don't know what the result should be.

Comment: Suggested test case: `["ab  ", "  b ", "   a"]` (where the columns are symmetric with the spaces stripped, but not with spaces present)

Comment: @Mnemonic that’s not a valid input since it has an odd number of columns. Thus submissions are allowed to behave in any way for this input.

Comment: @ngn This is similar to the `["ab", "ba"]` test case, result should be falsy (it’s a symmetry+rotation, while skew symmetry is only symmetry+translation).

Comment: @Grimy Formatting ate the array.  It's supposed to be four columns, with 'a' in the first and last and 'b' in the second and third.  So `["ab..", "..b.", "...a"]`, with the dots replaced with spaces.

Comment: Suggested test case: `["  ba","abdc","cd  "]` -> truthy (left part is moved downwards). May we assume, that the input contains only printable ASCII (`' '` (space) to `'~'`)?

Comment: @nimi Yes, you may assume.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>44</s> 34 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

<sub>[crossed out <s>44</s> is still regular 44 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170188/75323)</sub>

Hats off to @Bubbler, @ngn and @TesselatingHeckler as they managed to shave some bytes off of my solution, more or less independently but coming up with the same simplifications.

```apl
{1∊(l↓⍵)⍷⍨a/⍨∨⌿' '≠a←⊖⍵↑⍨l←2÷⍨≢⍵}⍉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rwUUeXRs6jtsmPerdqPurd/qh3RTWQqQ@kH3WseNSzX11B/VHnAqBQ7aOuaUDqUdtEoBxQxwSjwyDVjzoXgSV7O/@nKQBFFaqB@vR1qGQmF9ejvqlAcaDRYFrBWMHiUe8W9cTilDQFIMjKzrFOSylOBLGtc7Kz1NHVGyLUg9SpY5pnApJXUEhMSkpMSU5OUVCAqVFQx1BtpGAENg2oFpdJiUkgt4CJRPX/AA)

Now I'll explain **how it works**:

```apl
{                                   }⍉  ⍝ We define a monadic function that we apply right after transposing (⍉) the input [this means we will be operating on columns instead of rows]
                              2÷⍨≢⍵    ⍝ Start by finding how many  columns the input has (≢),split that in half (2÷⍨)
                            l←          ⍝   and assign that to l (l←) ...
                        ⍵↑⍨            ⍝ Using it right away to take (↑⍨) l columns from the original input ⍵
                       ⊖               ⍝   which we then reverse (⊖) [effectively flipping the columns upside down]
                     a←                 ⍝   and assign to a (a←)
                 ' '≠                   ⍝ We then compare each character in a to ' '
               ∨⌿                       ⍝   and we "interleave" the logical OR (∨) over the columns (⌿) [to find columns where at least one character is different from ' ']
           a/⍨                          ⍝   finally selecting those columns from a (a/⍨)
         ⍷⍨                             ⍝ Now we superimpose that piece of the original character matrix over all possible locations
   (l↓⍵)                               ⍝   of the columns of ⍵ that remain after we drop (↓) the first l columns [i.e. we take the second half of the columns]
 1∊                                    ⍝   and we look for matches by checking if there is a 1 (Truthy) in any position (∊)
```

Comment: Quick golf using transposed array gives [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRxwp9HY2cR22TH/Vu1XzUu/1R74pqIFMfSAPlHvXsV1dQf9S5AChU@6hrGpB61DYRKAfUMcHoMEj1o85FYMnezv9pCkBRBaqaycX1qG8qUBxoNJhWMFaweNS7RT2xOCVNAQiysnOs01KKE0Fs65zsLHV09YYI9SB16pjmmYDkFRQSk5ISU5KTUxQUYGoU1DFUGykYgU0DqsVlUmISyC1gIlH9PwA).

Comment: @Bubbler Quick for you ⍨ ahah, thanks for the help!

Comment: [33](https://tio.run/##dY6xCsIwEIZ3n@K2VFCK1UHo01wbKmhAoUOR4lraYkQRncUpD6A4Ovgm9yL1EhCx0gy5uz/ffQRXaijXqJazpslHVNZe5pM2VBraPgUIqi4ZFXuqz4qKI@l7n/SDixsMZ/vg9bAL1ZXTDemqSYBTyFnhD7yfLZNz29a7tfrsnIcOZ69HuxPnrHYVxjAlfROYygT4zBcqTGSKtg/VYi7a/OjLW078@yb2HQCjCGUcS4APA@KPDiBwNma7TBjZv7gLRfMG "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online"): `{1∊(w/⍨∨⌿' '≠w←⊖l↓⍵)⍷⍵↓⍨l←2÷⍨≢⍵}⍉`

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>34</s></sup> <sup><s>23</s></sup> 38 bytes

```
1 e.[:(e.&:((-:@#{.])"1)|."1\.)"2],:|.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRa4MwFIXf/RUHO3oVNKu2DyPB0TE2GOxprzaMxESKla2ghcH6311ifZilF0LCyXfuudxmCBnVKDgICVbg7qQMzx/vr0MGy0oeWbbkUZTy7eKXyTjM4jMLsx2Lw1wm/MyGOLDV/hs11tjgzvWBVkqbqjIABUFvu75gkKIU9VYGgSkY0XgZl5hBON@D96nO1HDVHFpRm075t2gPDf1nE34BPTD72CD3TUqMVdI84NZgE7ByQD6Z01TSDV1prWb6etKVG1JdOcYor2toH3PZTkRvX8dTT4Jefo626q0hAXqq@pNqKXbmzxx@U8vH@x3M8Ac)

*thanks to nimi for catching a bug*

Will attempt to regolf the fixed version later.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>137</s> <s>135</s> 133 bytes

```
f s=uncurry(#)$unzip$splitAt(div(length$s!!0)2)<$>s
a#b@(x:y)|e$last a++x=init a#y|e$last b++a!!0=b#a|r<-reverse<$>b=a==r
e=all(<'!')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxLTsMwEIb3OcXkIdVWCkIsaYzgAJwgitBM7FA3rhXZTtWg3j04EQ14MZ75/scRfa@MmecOvBhtOzo3sZwXo/3WQ@EHo8N7YFJfmFH2KxwLn6ZP/JlXxatPMKc3dn2Z@E0VBn0ALMur0FbHLZ/ukMoSY0hQjjdXPTh1Uc6rWEAChXCJEmgMq3bpjs9n1BYEnHH4@AQ2OG0DPHYc6gSgztDLDuLL9tmpN4dOeozrQg6mP2XNfnOt0u9dw2paRn1nALREkWQbv1ZGOSr/7M3WRvGkrQzX2Gr5YwALJaDY0iTzDw)