# Decomposition of a matrix in \$ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \$

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix, linear-algebra

### Background

The [special linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group) \$ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \$ is a multiplicative group of \$ 2 \times 2 \$ matrices whose elements are integers and determinant is 1.

It is known that every member of \$ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \$ is a product of some sequence of the following two matrices \$ S \$ and \$ T \$ ([reference pdf](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf)):

$$
S=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix},T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Note that \$ S^{-1} \$ and \$ T^{-1} \$ can also be expressed as a product of \$ S \$ and \$ T \$:

$$
S^{-1} = S^3, T^{-1} = S^3 \cdot T \cdot S \cdot T \cdot S
$$

### Task

Given a \$ 2 \times 2 \$ integer matrix whose determinant is 1, express it as the product of a sequence of \$ S \$ and \$ T \$.

Note that there are infinitely many possible answers for any valid input. Your code needs to just output one answer for a valid input.

### Example algorithm

Here is a sample algorithm to find a decomposition; you may use different algorithms to solve the task.

First, note that

$$
M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \implies
S^{-1}M = \begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ -a & -b \end{pmatrix},
T^{-1}M = \begin{pmatrix} a-c & b-d \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
$$

Using these two operations, we can use Euclidean-like algorithm to reduce the given matrix down to \$ I \$, and then construct the chain backwards:

1. Assume \$ M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \$.
2. Left-multiply \$ S^{-1} \$ until both \$ a \$ and \$ c \$ are positive.
3. Repeat the following until we reach \$ c = 0 \$:

   1. Left-multiply \$ T^{-q} \$ where \$ -c < a - qc \le 0 \$.
   2. Left-multiply \$ S^{-1} \$ (exactly once). Now, \$a\$ and \$c\$ are positive again, and \$c\$ is smaller than the original.
4. Then the result is \$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \$, which is simply \$ T^b \$. (If \$ b < 0 \$, we can use \$ (SSSTSTS)^{-b} \$ instead.) Now invert all the left-multiplications to get the representation for the original matrix.

Here is an example for \$ M = \begin{pmatrix}17 & 29\\7 & 12\end{pmatrix} \$.

$$
T^{-3} M = \begin{pmatrix}-4 & -7\\7 & 12\end{pmatrix}
\\ S^{-1} T^{-3} M = \begin{pmatrix}7 & 12\\4 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\\ T^{-2} S^{-1} T^{-3} M = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & -2\\4 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\\ S^{-1} T^{-2} S^{-1} T^{-3} M = \begin{pmatrix}4 & 7\\1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\\ T^{-4} S^{-1} T^{-2} S^{-1} T^{-3} M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\\ S^{-1} T^{-4} S^{-1} T^{-2} S^{-1} T^{-3} M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = T^2
\\ M = T^3 S T^2 S T^4 S T^2
$$

### Input and output

You can take the input matrix in any suitable way, e.g. a matrix, a 4-element vector, two complex numbers, etc. You can assume that the input is always valid, i.e. the four elements are integers and the determinant is 1.

The output is a sequence of two distinct values (or objects) that represent \$ S \$ and \$ T \$ respectively. All of the following are accepted (using an example output \$ STTS \$):

```
"STTS"  # string
"0110"  # digit string
[0, 1, 1, 0]  # array of 0s and 1s
['S', 'T', 'T', 'S']  # array of characters
[(0,-1,1,0), (1,1,0,1), (1,1,0,1), (0,-1,1,0)]  # array of tuples
```

Also, by definition of [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product), an empty sequence (e.g. `""` or `[]`) is a valid answer when the input is \$ I \$.

### Scoring and winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Example I/O

Note that every valid input has infinitely many correct answers, so your code's output may differ from the sample outputs shown here.

```
[[1 0]
 [0 1]] -> empty or SSSS or SSSTSTST or ...

[[0 -1]
 [1  0]] -> S

[[1 10]
 [0  1]] -> TTTTTTTTTT

[[17 29]
 [ 7 12]] -> TTTSTTSTTTTSTT

[[-1  -7]
 [-2 -15]] -> SSTSTTSTSSTTTTSSTTT
```

Comment: I feel like most of the solutions are going to brute force the order rather than follow the given algorithm. Not that that's a bad thing though, and I would be interested to see if the algorithm can be implemented more precisely than that

Comment: A harder test case: `[ [-5, 14], [16, -45] ] -> STTTTSTTSTTSTTSTTTSTTSTS`

Comment: What does your example algorithm do if after getting `c=0`, you have that `b` is negative, giving a negative power of T?

Comment: @Noodle9 1st question: "Left-multiply \$ S^{-1} \$" is the procedure, the rest is the description of what that step achieves. 2nd question: There are many possible answers, including yours and mine.

Comment: @xnor One possible solution would be to put `-b` copies of `SSSTSTS` since \$ T^{-1} \$ is precisely equal to that.

Comment: @Noodle9 Look at the worked example and see how the left column reduces from `17, 7` to `7, 4`, `4, 1`, and then `1, 0`. Does it help? (The whole algorithm works like the Euclidean algorithm for finding GCD, just that it works on the left column of the matrix, and hitting a negative number before doing the "recursion".)

Comment: @Bubbler I'm also confused. If you start with `a=1, c=4`, don't you get `q=1`, giving you `(1,4) -> (-3,4) -> (4,3)`? I think this requires a particular ordering to count as "smaller", where you first sort by `c`.

Comment: @xnor Yes it does, but the seeming "increase" only happens once: `1,4 (T)-> -3,4 (S)-> 4,3 (T)-> -2,3 (S)-> 3,2 (T)-> -1,2 (S)-> 2,1 (T)-> 0,1 (S)-> 1,0`. In general, it may happen at most once because `a>c` is guaranteed after one step. But you're right about the "smaller"; I'll edit the post to reflect the point.

Comment: @Noodle9 I tried to clarify the algorithm in the post. Does it look better for you?

Comment: @Bubbler I feel as if a dark and treacherous sky has cleared and bright happy sunshine is once again lighting up the world! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
g=lambda z,w:(z/w).real>0and'T'+g(z-w,w)or z+w*w and'S'+g(w,-z)or''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNb9swDD1Hv4LoDrEcObMMtMUMeECPPeTS5GYYg2wpqQt/QVLm1sN@e0Y6HjJ0gGE@vkdS0uPw4V/7LrlcTlmj2lIrmMSYBtPXkW@tUc33WHV6fVhvTsEUjWLkvYVpM4YjEL8nfhTRhPR6fTmiqEQpKqGh7iDPpYB4/mQhIMcYIUMkpQTkIkMhcvkoIPkmAINMMKfaCJMoob77okjZarB15@EUqI18C/EgCpoz9gWeoO2tAfP@qs7O1z8NeOM8q9uhtx66czt8MLbPZrBtlbf1e5DjlSJJR4u4KDg7fJalIDXGP6rs@X85/kfWlYcMfqEpKewFoGkpHH4jb46gTdVrEzieMrDGnRsqfWZAjlXklUtv/AJCwIl5VVCHP9tu4Rl7oRrVnUwQPYhHzuihPyrljEMhD5YN8Hm4ouEvMyxvsLpBfYX1EVSoozKsskwWjJHkSboNR/v/LjcDz1Y7DJ8MQR0NwQoyZGXnC9GyylC@4bI0BuR3CdKLI1iDjHLO4JYCUjLY8a1qmoALIgSm7Lr2u6emges7B@rQd5c/)

*Thanks to Bubbler for cutting a byte*

Takes input as two complex numbers for the rows. The idea is simple and easy-to-see on a less-golfed version:

```python
def f(a,b,c,d):
 if (a,b,c,d)==(1,0,0,1): return ''
 elif a*c+b*d>0: return 'T'+f(a-c,b-d,c,d)
 else: return 'S'+f(c,d,-a,-b)
```

From \$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\$, we choose whether to apply \$S^{-1}\$ or  \$T^{-1}\$ based on a simple condition: whether \$ac+bd>0\$. Repeating this enough times takes any matrix to the identity.

Comment: Now *that* is how to use complex numbers for golfing.

Comment: [67 bytes.](https://tio.run/##ZVFNb9swDD1Hv4LoDrEcObMMtMUMeECPPeTS5GYYg2wpqQt/QVLm1sN@e0Y6HjJ0gGE@vkdS0uPw4V/7LrlcTlmj2lIrmMSYBtPXkW@tUc33WHV6fVhvTsEUjWLkvYVpM4YjEL8nfhTRhPR6fTmiqEQpKqGh7iDPpYB4/mQhIMcYIUMkpQTkIkMhcvkoIPkmAINMMKfaCJMoob77okjZarB15@EUqI18C/EgCpoz9gWeoO2tAfP@qs7O1z8NeOM8q9uhtx66czt8MLbPZrBtlbf1e5DjlSJJR4u4KDg7fJalIDXGP6rs@X85/kfWlYcMfqEpKewFoGkpHH4jb46gTdVrEzieMrDGnRsqfWZAjlXklUtv/AJCwIl5VVCHP9tu4Rl7oRrVnUwQPYhHzuihPyrljEMhD5YN8Hm4ouEvMyxvsLpBfYX1EVSoozKsskwWjJHkSboNR/v/LjcDz1Y7DJ8MQR0NwQoyZGXnC9GyylC@4bI0BuR3CdKLI1iDjHLO4JYCUjLY8a1qmoALIgSm7Lr2u6emges7B@rQd5c/)

Comment: @Bubbler Nice one, thanks

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

This is using [xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198036/58563) -- but obviously without complex numbers.

Takes the input matrix \$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\$ as 4 distinct parameters `a,b,c,d`.

Returns a string of digits (\$0\$ for \$S\$, \$1\$ for \$T\$).

```javascript
f=(a,b,c,d)=>b|c|a-1|d-1?a*c>-b*d?1+f(a-c,b-d,c,d):0+f(c,d,-a,-b):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBDoIwEETv/ggtzhqWgEQS4Fu2LRgNoUaMJ/69brwZzFw27@3MXd6y@uft8aIlhjGlqTMCB49gu95tfhPiLRAPkvueXB4GPk5GyMNR@L61hQI9QAJyts2y5OOyxnk8zfFqJsMoNGzt4ZcXIIbKnVD6v8ENygsacLlTOkUNqNTNei9rcAU@gyqV6QM)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>114 110</s>  108 bytes

Takes the input matrix \$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\$ as a 4-element vector `[a,b,c,d]`.

Returns a string of digits (\$0\$ for \$S\$, \$1\$ for \$T\$).

Brute forces a solution, which is guaranteed to be as short as possible, except for the identity matrix.

```javascript
f=(M,i=0)=>(F=(a,b,c,d,s='')=>s[i]?a+[,b,c,d]==M&&s:F(a,a+b,c,c+d,s+1)||F(b,-a,d,-c,s+0))(1,0,0,1)||f(M,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BDoIwEEX3HgSm6dS0JIZoMrpjxwkIi1LAYAg11rji7nUaXRnM7N77/8/Nvmxwj@n@VIvvhxhHghon0oLOUBFY7NBhj4HynFFopvZiZfOhLVGdZeFUcczKhJzkqDRiXSvoUFluKsdECwEGNV9yY3rBqej8Evw87Gd/hRGab6IVYvdjNCqDrDcU838tU2JxxBJNsSF5UJWoCl4@sI5v)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                      // f = wrapper function taking:
  M,                       //   M[] = input vector
  i = 0                    //   i   = maximum number of iterations (-1)
) => (                     //
  F = (                    // F is a recursive function taking:
    a, b, c, d,            //   the current matrix as 4 distinct parameters
    s = ''                 //   s = output string
  ) =>                     //
    s[i] ?                 // if we've reached the maximum length:
      a + [, b, c, d] == M //   if [a, b, c, d] matches the input matrix:
        && s               //     return s
    :                      // else:
      F(                   //   try a first recursive call
        a,                 //     where the matrix is multiplied by T
        a + b,             //     [ a b ]   [ 1 1 ]   [ a a+b ]
        c,                 //     [ c d ] x [ 0 1 ] = [ c c+d ]
        c + d,             //
        s + 1              //     append '1' to s
      ) ||                 //
      F(                   //   try a second recursive call
        b,                 //     where the matrix is multiplied by S
        -a,                //     [ a b ]   [ 0 -1 ]   [ b -a ]
        d,                 //     [ c d ] x [ 1  0 ] = [ d -c ]
        -c,                //
        s + 0              //     append '0' to s
      )                    //
)(1, 0, 0, 1)              // initial call to F with the identity matrix
|| f(M, i + 1)             // if it fails, try again with i + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 47 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Gives Boolean list with 0 and 1 meaning \$S\$ and \$T\$ respectively.

```apl
{⍺≡⊃+.×/(r←⊤⍵)⊇2 2∘⍴¨(0 ¯1 1)(1 1 0):r⋄⍺∇1+⍵}∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sf9e561LnwUVeztt7h6foaRUDRR11LHvVu1XzU1W6kYPSoY8aj3i2HVmgYKBxab6hgqKkBJBQMNK2KHnW3gDR3tBtqA5XXAhUa/k8Dae/tg5jf1XxovfGjtolAXnCQM5AM8fAM/p@mADK1dwvQECA05ILxoeYrGHAhVBiiKjE0VzCyVDBXMDSCC4H0HFpvDsRGIP2mAA) ([Faster edition](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXCFA0uhR19JHvYsPrTd81LWIyxMo8qhn@6PeFY86ZjzqagIy/lc/6t31qHPho65mbb3D0/U1ioBqQh71btX0VDBSMAKp691yaIWGgQLQDAVDTQ0goWCgaVX0qLsFpLOj3VAbqLoWqNDwfxrI/N4@iBO6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9PApvZuARoChIZcMD7UfAUDLoQKQ1QlhuYKRpYK5gqGRnAhkJ5D682B2Aik3xQA) emulating Extended in Unicode.)

`{`…`}∘1` apply the following function with 1 and the given matrix as right and left arguments:

`(0 ¯1 1)(1 1 0)` the list `[[0,-1,1],[1,1,0]]`

`2 2∘⍴¨` **r**eshape each into a 2-by-2 matrix; `[[[0,-1],[1,0]],[[1,1],[0,1]]]`

`(`…`)⊇` select the following elements from that:

`⊤` convert the right argument **T**o base **T**wo

`r←` store that in `r` (potential **r**esult)

`+.×/` reduce using matrix multiplication (this also reduces the number of dimensions from 1 to 0)

`⊃` disclose (the enclosure necessitated to reduce the number of dimensions)

`⍺≡`…`:` if the left argument (the target matrix) matches that, then:

`r` return the **r**esult

`⋄` else:

`1+⍵` increment the right argument

`⍺∇` call self with same left argument and new right argument

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>48</s>  <s>44</s>  <s>43</s> 40 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

[<sup>*Crossed out `&nbsp;44&nbsp;` is no longer 44 :)*</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)

```
9bS[)DðýIk©d#¼vyDÁ0T·Sǝ+y2Å€(}2ôí˜]T¾ã®è
```

`9bS` and `DÁ0T·Sǝ+` could alternatively be `9Yв`/`т1ª`/`тĆS`/`TºS` and `D2ôO13Sǝ`/`DÁ2Å€0}+` for the same byte-count.

Brute-force approach with pretty bad performance (it times out for the last three test cases - the previous 48;44;43 bytes versions only timed out for the last test case).

Input \$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\$ as a space-delimited string of four integers `"a b c d"`.
Output as a string of `0`s and `1`s, where `0` is \$S\$ and `1` is \$T\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AU4Asf9vc2FiaWX//zliU1spRMOww71Ja8KpZCPCvHZ5RMOBMFTCt1PHnSt5MsOF4oKsKH0yw7TDrcucXVTCvsOjwq7DqP//LTQgLTMgLTEgLTE) or [verify a few test cases at once](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXof8uk4GhNl8MbDu@NyD60MkX50J6ySpfDjQYhh7YHH5@rXWl0uPVR0xqNWqPDWw6vPT2ntjbk0L7Diw@tO7ziv4t9yKOGeSHBjxoWHtpxeo6XkoLG4f2aSjoxeoe2/o9WMlQwAEJDJR0lAwVdQwUgF8jUNVbQNQJxdUEShgrGYLYRSMYIqMRUQddYKRYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
9bS                # Push 9, convert it to binary, and then to a digit-list: [1,0,0,1]
   [               # Start an infinite loop:
    )              #  Wrap all lists on the stack into a list
     D             #  Duplicate the current list of lists
      ðý           #  Join each inner list to a string with space delimiter
        Ik         #  Get the index of the input-string in this list
                   #  (the join is a work-around for lack of non-vectorizing index builtin)
          ©        #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
           d       #  Check if this index is non-negative (>= 0)
            #      #  And it it is: stop the infinite loop
    ¼              #  Increase the counter variable by 1 
      v            #  Loop over each inner [a,b,c,d]-list `y`:
       yD          #   Push the list twice
         Á         #   Rotate the second one once towards the right: [a,b,c,d] → [d,a,b,c]
           T·S     #   Push 10 doubled as digit list: [2,0]
          0   ǝ    #   Insert a 0 at those (0-based) indices: [0,a,0,c]
               +   #   Add it to the earlier list: [a+0,b+a,c+0,d+c] → [a,b+a,c,d+c]
       y           #   Get the initial list [a,b,c,d] again
        2Å€ }      #   Apply to every 0-based 2nd item (so at indices [0,2]):
           (       #    Negate
             2ô    #   Split the list into parts of size 2: [-a,b,-c,d] → [[-a,b],[-c,d]]
               í˜  #   Reverse each, and flatten: → [[b,-a],[d,-c]] → [b,-a,d,-c]
   ]               # Close both the map and infinite loop
    T¾ã            # Take the cartesian product of 10 with the counter variable
                   #  i.e. 3 → ["111","110","101","100","011","010","001","000"]
       ®è          # And index variable `®` into this list
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>42</s> <s>38</s> 32 bytes

```
`@B"@?FT!tqh}IlhB]]Nq:"Y*]G-z}@B
```

The code enumerates all finite sequences that begin with `S`, and stops when a solution is found. It is sufficient to test sequences beginning with `S` because `S*S*S*S` equals the identity matrix (inspiration from [@Adam's APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198015/36398)).

Outputs a binary sequence, where `1` corresponds to matrix `S` and `0` to matrix `T`. The produced solution is the first in lexicographical order.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HBScnB3i1EsaQwo9YzJ8MpNtav0EopUivWXbeq1sHp//9oQwUDawUDBcNYAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>301</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>139</s></sup> 129 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,c,d,l=''):
 while c:
  while 0>a or b<0:a,b,c,d=c,d,-a,-b;l+='S'
  if c:q=-a//c;a+=q*c;b+=q*d;l+='T'*-q
 return l+'T'*b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwEEX3fMXETXlMw8MYIliX/oDuCIsWqJAQXtYYQ/x2nBpXc@@dcyczvU07DvttqxsN2pWosMIae8GYlznwaru@gYrUX0ZnCeMC6hRlf1ZYnkvkKu8Dwa6M2E5TZxZchmGVy0DMfpUrO@ofc2M@nx1YGvNcBugDG6hN013TPAx0AxRFhDzGGKMSizjF5IgpxgkZSnmKPKH1oSzpsWnpBuPq3YXqq@1/4D4aYKt2fWu9D9t5zvYF)

Saved 18 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

Takes the 4 matrix elements as separate numbers as input and outputs a string of `'S'`s and `'T'`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>24</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁽¬Pb3’s2$⁺⁸ṃæ×/⁼
0ç1#B
```

A monadic Link accepting the target matrix which outputs a list containing a single list of `1`s (\$S\$) and `0`s (\$T\$).
As a full program a Jelly representation of this list is printed.

Always yields a resulting equation with a leading \$S\$ (except for an input of \$T\$ itself).
Note that since \$S^4=I\$ this is always possible.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9qZWxsef//4oG9wqxQYjPigJlzMiTigbrigbjhuYPDpsOXL@KBvAoww6cxI0L///9bWzEsIDEwXSwgWzAsIDFdXQ)** (very slow in general).

#### How?

Starts with `i=0` and increments `i` while the binary representation of `i` with digits \$S\$ (1) and \$T\$ (0) does not have a matrix-product equal to the input, then returns the normal binary representation (using 1s and 0s).

```
⁽¬Pb3’s2$⁺⁸ṃæ×/⁼ - Link 1: integer, i; target matrix, M
⁽¬P              - literal 2831
   b3            - to base three    [1,0,2,1,2,2,1,2]
     ’           - decrement        [0,-1,1,0,1,1,0,1]
      s2$        - split into twos  [[0,-1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]]
         ⁺       - repeat that      [[[0,-1],[1,0]],[[1,1],[0,1]]]
          ⁸ṃ     - base-decompression of i
                 -     -> i in binary using digits 1=[[0,-1],[1,0]] and 0=[[1,1],[0,1]]
            æ×/  - reduce by matrix-multiplication
               ⁼ - is equal to M?

0ç1#B            - Main Link: 2-by-2 target matrix with determinant 1, M
0                - initialise the left argument, say i, to 0
  1#             - count up finding the first match under:
 ç               -   last Link (1) as a dyad - i.e. f(i, M)
    B            - convert to binary
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 64 bytes

```
Ｗ∨§η⁰⊖§θ⁰¿‹⁰×§θ⁰§η⁰«TＵＭθ⁻κ§ηλ»«S≔±θι≔ηθ≔ιη»×TΠθ¿›⁰Πθ«SSS×TST±ΠθS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Na8MwDIbP9a8QPbkgQzsYPfRUNhiD9QPSW8jBJFpj5jiL7W6D0d/u2svYHN9k6Xn0qm6lrXupQ/hslSbgB8u3/tk09MVbhOUC4ZFqSx0ZT81fa0it@EC9An8h5/gS4aQ6ctMRhIksEd9sdrTKeD4/zRcbNtvJ94e@66RpErJT5uL424TTEduwK5B2lOHFD751Tp0N39NZeuJD3Kiy70gPWakQ2qRio2IMHHMgHG3fXGofBWlXuurJUjTadFjezAMUY4SprEi63zg5@D85Jr@GUJZihQBiXSGDUtwhiNV9VQXxoW8) Link is to verbose version of code. Based on the provided algorithm. Explanation:

```
Ｗ∨§η⁰⊖§θ⁰
```

Repeat while the first column is not `[1, 0]`.

```
¿‹⁰×§θ⁰§η⁰
```

If the product of the first column is positive...

```
«TＵＭθ⁻κ§ηλ»
```

... then print a `T` and subtract the second row from the first row...

```
«S≔±θι≔ηθ≔ιη»
```

... otherwise print an `S`, and swap the rows, while negating the second row.

```
×TΠθ
```

If the product of the first row is positive then print that many `T`s.

```
¿›⁰Πθ«
```

But if it is negative, then...

```
SSS×TST±ΠθS
```

... print `SSS`, the appropriate number of `TST`s, and a final `S`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 96 bytes

```ruby
->m{z=[['',1,0,0,1]];z.find{|a,q,w,e,r|z<<[a+?S,w,-q,r,-e]<<[a+?T,q,q+w,e,e+r];m==[q,w,e,r]}[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3foW7LnojSUGCtNGP0N0wi4oNuKiYQBH7@PY4VSvIrM6dc2did34m75Lat0PviLIMBlrGMJf9xl9vl2GsEfBAgzj2VUV1fjgKqoAI1fAnOYkS8llq8shl6xx9OzyR5ind157od3r1Rg1l5ncLC/ztjUWxg4UplkR8ZaEKKW6Z0ws)

Use the (brute) force.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>193</s> <s>192</s> 191 bytes

Takes in a 2D numpy array and returns a string of S and T. Uses the algorithm in the question.

```python
import numpy
def g(m,x=0):
 if m[1,0]==0:y=m[0,1];return['T','SSSTSTS'][y<0]*abs(y)
 while(m[:,0]<[1,0]).any():x+=1;m=[[0,1],[-1,0]]@m
 q=-m[0,0]//m[1,0];return'S'*x+'T'*-q+g([[1,q],[0,1]]@m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY9LDoMgFEXnroIZoKCQ1g5Uku5BZ4SBTf0lBZVqKqu3aJs3vPfckze5pR/NZd8HPY12AWbVkwueTQs6pMkmGM4CMLRAS06YEoJlTmjJCFe5bZbVGgkrSGBZlpU/qKQrmArrxxs5HIBPP7wapGXm2eJcwHFtHMLZFgmeayHPKSLpkam7DsAs6LHPVJL8nH8PLGG4RV4W0jnqkPTZ7MED9xzeJzuYBXXofCCura2dL9GU8Kuv8Ruh11QpjPH@BQ)