# Is it a doubling sequence?

Tags: code-golf, number

A doubling sequence is an array of numbers where each subsequent number is at least twice the previous number.

Given an ordered list of numbers, determine if the numbers in the list (\$n_{x}\$) have the property that:

\$n_1 \times 2 \le n_2\$

\$n_2 \times 2 \le n_3\ ...\$

and so on until reaching the end of the list.

## Input

A list of two or more numbers.

## Output

Any distinct True or False value.

## Examples:

```
[10,20,30] -> False
[10,20,40] -> True
[1,2,3] -> False
[1,2,4] -> True
[1,2,10] -> True
[1,1] -> False
[10,1] -> False
```

Comment: Can input be sorted in either order?

Comment: Pre-sorted in that it may be sorted ascending, descending, or some other order, but you don't have to change the order of the list that is fed to the function.

Comment: Since inputs can be non-integers, do we care about floating point precision? Many of these solution fail for n_i+1 = n_i*(2-epislon) for some fairly large epsilons

Comment: what about negative numbers? what about the sequence of zeros?

Comment: "some other order" can be any reflexive transitive antisymmetric relation. In other words, your definition admits arbitrary order of the elements, which I'd guess is not what you intended.

Comment: @kyrill, I assume what's meant is that the input list of numbers aren't guaranteed to be in any particular order, however the result could only be `True` if they are sorted ascendingly. My assumption at least...

Comment: I see. That explains the last example.

Comment: is this limited to integers or does one have to accommodate decimals also?

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```r
all(diff(log2(scan()))>=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzEnRyMlMy1NIyc/3UijODkxT0NTU9PO1lDzv6GCkYKhwX8A)

1 byte saved by Giuseppe.

Answer (score 10):

## Jelly, 4 (5?) bytes

Monadic link taking the list as input.

```
I<ṖẸ
```

If I am allowed to output 0 for Truthy and 1 for Falsy... Otherwise,

```
I<ṖẸ¬
```

You can [try all test cases](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/T5uHOaQ937Ti05v/h9kdNa/7/j442NNAxMtAxNojV4YKyTSBsHSMdYxjDBMYwhMoZQpUbxsYCAA)!

Notice that \$x_{i+1} \geq 2x_i \iff x_{i+1} - x_i \geq x_i\$.

```
 <      Compare
I       the forward differences
  Ṗ     with the original list without the last item.
   Ẹ    Check if any comparison returned true
    ¬   and negate that
```

## Jelly, 6 bytes

We can instead take pairwise quotients and check directly if they satisfy the inequality with this monadic link:

```
÷Ɲ>.Ẹ¬
```

You can [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9mNz7fQe7tpxaM3/w@2Pmtb8/x8dbWigY2SgY2wQq8MFZZtA2DpGOsYwhgmMYQiVM4QqN4yNBQA)!

```
÷Ɲ      Compute the quotient for all pairs of elements in the input list.
  >.    See if the elements are greater than 0.5
    Ẹ   and take the "OR" of that list,
     ¬  finishing off with the negation of that.
```

Comment: Any distinct True and False values are allowed, so you can define the distinct True and False values chosen as `False` and `True` to eliminate the final `¬`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ä÷ e§½
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=5PcgZae9&input=WzEsMiwxMF0)

```
ä÷ e§½     :Implicit input of array
ä          :Consecutive pairs
 ÷         :  Reduced by division
   e       :All
    §½     :  Less than or equal to 0.5
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
f(x:s)=any(<2)$zipWith(/)s$x:s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02jwqpY0zYxr1LDxkhTpSqzIDyzJENDX7NYBSjxPzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFITexQCFNITra0EDHyEDH2CBWB8o0ATN1jHSMobQJlDaESBhCVBrGxv4HAA)

`True` for false and `False` for true.

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYpBDsIgEAC/sgcPkKwKtEd4h4fKYdOIJVKyabno410Ty2kmmVlofz1KkRTuQvWtvNMX9cl8y21RVx28b5SLlpVyhQC85drgBCsxJJgma9AZHEzEruNf0eHQOXbaI9jjtDHKd06FnrucZ@Yf) as a pointfree function.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>37</s> 29 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to xnor.

Fails for doubling sequences, completes otherwise.

```python
f=lambda a,*b:2*a<=b[0]>f(*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY89C4NADIb3@xVZxFNS8GuSnlsL3buJw1lPKliVuwj66@1pKaV1a4YkPLz5eIeZ7n0XL0stWvkoKwkS/TKNfHkUZR4UWc390ltIGTIggDPgeRhgFGAcFAhn2Rrl4YcmK73q8Q0xwvhHZ1GyE4W/c@Fu@4d48EcwVvcaCBU0HWx@UgZAel4LgPVJ3tZpZcaWrNntmEVquqmB4NJVajpp3ev0W7e@zSwadNMRdx0DhwxsFsJm1@GELynaz5cn)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,*b:b==()or 2*a<=b[0]and f(*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY@/CoMwHIR3n@LolMivEP9M0nTsE3QThwQTKtgomkKL@OypLRRBt974cXfw9S9/61wWgpWtuutaQVGsCy0l492ANFYnqUtRKVfDsljz4M3oR0iwCKxMBKWCMlERLqodDaeV5h96HR4/SCllm96C8l0p2e6S3ftKOP5IFNnFzZNB4/D1KSL0Q@M8s4fJzzieMS22ns8wzx6TmQ88vAE) Test suite by Noodle9.

Comment: In your second solution, it looks like you can shorter the check to `2*a<=b[0]*f(*b)`, it least assuming all values are positive. I'm not sure if the challenge allows switching True and False, but that might also allow a shorter condition. Likewise, the first answer might be shorter if failure corresponds to True, and is achieved when `b[0]` hits an empty list.

Comment: @xnor Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into the second answer later

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>26</s>  24 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Grimmy*

```javascript
a=>!a.some(n=>2*a>(a=n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc2xDsIgEIDh3ac4NzDYHrQrjD6Bm2G4VGo0yJmivj5qotFEZf/y/we6Uh6m/em8TLwNZbSFrJtTk/kYRLLOLMgJsknKMnDKHEMTeSdGsdGoDKoOvZTQtrCimMPsp@lfZj1dvokyqvMAUMvcTf82/zIafZ3oR6N@wif6MOUG)

Comment: [-2 bytes by reusing a](https://tio.run/##fc2xDsIgEIDh3ac4NzDYHrQrjD6Bm2G4VGo0yJmivj5qotFEZf/y/we6Uh6m/em8TLwNZbSFrJtTk/kYRLLOLMgJsknKMnDKHEMTeSdGsdGoDKoOvZTQtrCimMPsp@lfZj1dvokyqvMAUMvcTf82/zIafZ3oR6N@wif6MOUG)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Λ·≤D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zsQ9sfdS5x@f//f7ShjpGOoUEsAA)

Returns 0 if False, a positive number if True.

```
Λ     Check if adjacent pairs of elements satisfy the predicate
 · D    by doubling the first number
  ≤     and checking if the second number is less than it
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
∧/2≤2÷/÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEcdy/WNHnUuMTq8Xf/wdqCYgqGBgpGBgrEBF4xpAmYqGCkYQ2kTKG0IkTCEqDQEAA)

Comment: Nice! Beats mine by more than half; would you be so kind as to provide a decomposition/explanation?

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 18 bytes

```matlab
@(e)istril(e<2*e')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1Uzs7ikKDNHI9XGSCtVXfN/mka0oYGOkYGOsUGsJhecZwLk/QcA)

Octave has a nice feature known as broadcasting. Here, we take broadcast less-than of the input and the input doubled, by transposing the input. This creates a matrix of ones and zeroes. Iff this matrix is lower triangular (no nonzero entries above the diagonal), the sequence is a doubling sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>46</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```matlab
@(n)all(2*n(1:end-1)<=n(2:end))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zdZBI08zMSdHw0grT8PQKjUvRddQ08Y2T8MIxNbU/J@mEW1ooGNkoGNiEKv5HwA)

Thanks to Luis Mendo for `all`. Much shorter!

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?page=2&tab=oldest#tab-top Use pre-defined variables as IO is a standard loophole

Comment: @Vlo oh, I need to make it a function?

Comment: @LuisMendo Nice! I never knew about `all`...

Comment: Since you don't need the name f in your function you can save 2 bytes by not including f= as part of your code and having an anonymous function

Comment: Thought you might be interested in seeing a [different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199629/32352) at just 18 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>57</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>44</s></sup> 43 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [kaya3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91685/kaya3)!!!

```python
lambda l:all(b>=a*2for a,b in zip(l,l[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY/BCoJAFEX38xWPVjPxAkddCbrsC9qZi5FmSHjpoC@oxG@fMghBd93l4d4Lxz/52rVJcPk5kLnVFwOUGSJZF7nZx67rwWANTQuvxktCKnVWKRXYDjxADlKALHWEcYRJVCEcDQ1W4ULTmZ76@w9ijMmq90HppqTXO715X4iCPyLEbMdoZ7uvTybA903L0u1GnuBQwOgkqwnsw8Nop50Kbw)

Comment: You can save one byte by writing `b>=a*2for` without the space.

Comment: @kaya3 Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>53</del> <del>49</del> <del>47</del> 43 bytes

```php
for(;$argv[$i++]*2<=$k=$argv[$i];);echo!$k;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVEovSy6JVMrW1Y7WMbGxVsm1hIrHWmtapyRn5iirZ1v///zf8b/Tf0OC/kQEA)

-4 bytes thanks to @Kaddath.

Comment: That's actually really clever!

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by getting rid of the function: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQytbWtNVRybFUSi9LLNKNB/FgtIxtblWxblRwgN9Za0zo1OSNfUSXb@v///4b/jf4bGvw3MQAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rR`, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
1&÷{!;|":'½≤⑾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUO3w9mpF6xolK/VDex91Lnk0cd///9GGOgpGOgrGsf91i4IA)

*-2 bytes thanks to @a'_'*

### Answer History

#### 15 Bytes

```
1&÷^{!;|":'2*≥⑾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUO3w9rhqResaJSt1I61HnUsfTdz3/3@0oY6CkY6Ccex/3aIgAA)

I'm quite happy with this answer, and I'm quite happy with the explanation.

**Explained**

```
1&
```

First, we store the number 1 in the register. This will end up being the means by which the result is shown.

```
÷^
```

We then item split the input list and reverse it, so that things are in descending order.

```
{!;|
```

Now, we start a while loop that will run while the length of the stack - 1 is not zero.

```
":'
```

This bit of the algorithm took me a while to visualise and write... I had to resort to move playing cards around my living room floor to understand which stack shifting mechanics to use.

Lets say the input stack (after item splitting and reversal) is `[4, 2, 1]`. Right shifting the stack (`"`) gives `[1, 4, 2]`, duplicating the top gives `[1, 4, 2, 2]` and then left shifting the stack (`'`) gives `[4, 2, 2, 1]`.

We do this so that we can compare the top of the stack with the next item and preserve that second item (in other words, circumnavigate the side effects of operators consuming stack items).

```
2*≥
```

We then multiply the top item by two and see if the result is greater than or equal to the next item in the series.

```
⑾
```

The result is then augmented multiplied into the register and the while loop continues.

`-rR` prints the value of the register at the end of execution as an integer.

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUO3w9mpF6xolK/VDex91Lnk0cd///9GGOgpGOgomsf91i4IA) after *not* reversing the stack before the operation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->l{x,*l=l;l.all?{|y|x*2<=x=y}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxCoAgEIDhV2mOS9Tc6upB5AYbmi6IIDhRn92GdPvg/5/3iPXEOm2cBEZGXlgF5j3lmGW0KwrGUqr3RoPVMGuCodn9Bgtzh@swrZm2GyJ1hTtlyffgBU4vRKV@)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

[<sup>Crossed out 4 is still regular 4 ;(</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)

```
¥›à
```

Outputs `0` for truthy and `1` for falsey.

Port of [*@RGS*' first Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199416/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-1 byte thanks for *@Grimmy* for mentioning any two distinct truthy/falsey values are allowed, so I can drop the invert at the end

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0NJHDbsOL/j/P9rQQMfIQMfEIBYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRf6fL/0NJHDbsOL/iv8z862tBAx8hAx9ggVgfKNAEzdYx0jKG0CZQ2hEgYQlQaxsYCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
¥    # Get the deltas (forward differences) of the (implicit) input-list
 ›   # Check for each whether it's larger than value at the same position in the (implicit)
     # input-list, which automatically ignores the trailing item of the input
  à  # Get the maximum of this, to check if any are truthy
     # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: The spec allow `Any distinct True or False value`, so you can cut the `_`.

Comment: @Grimmy Ah, hadn't noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```clj
(fn[s](every? #(<= 2%)(map /(rest s)s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxCoAwEETRPqcYEGG3EBO11oOIhWhSiEZJYuHpo53bzYPhL/u53cFmWq2Dy@T8GCfyZ6pm/wwoqEeDkumYL9QUbEyIHJk5s6IreAVyGI1Go9HqiaW731@klegkjPgZkfg25xc)

Basically the obvious pairwise thing, with a fun way to generate consecutive pairs of a sequence.

Comment: But it is still a tad shorter to reverse the comparison to a more common [every?](https://tio.run/##Tcy7CgIxEIXhPk9xYBFmqs2tVHyQkELWSSEaQ@IKPn20c7rzweHf7s/b3mXSVQrKpFLTyCRv6Z8zFjqe4A9Mj0vDSl3GC4MHM0821Ho1oILkLLxFsJm149/wCBpRw6mfU4nf5vkF). And amusingly enough, Clojure also doesn't complain after removing the space after 2 :)

Comment: `not-any`? What a confusing way to spell `none`.

Comment: @KirillL. good catch.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 54 bytes

```lua
for i=2,#arg do b=b or arg[i-1]*2>0+arg[i]end print(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWSEc5sShdISVfIck2SQEoBORFZ@oaxmoZ2RlogzmxqXkpCgVFmXklGkma////NzT4b2Tw38QAAA)

`true` and `false` are swapped.

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, 41 Bytes

```
f(n)=1-l(n[2n[0...l(n)]>n])
l(n)=n.length
```

[Try It Over Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u24c7rpumy?nographpaper)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 49 bytes

```powershell
param($n)($n|?{$_-ge2*$l;$l=$_}).count-eq$n.count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPE4hr7KtV4nXTU420VHKsVXJsVeJrNfWS80vzSnRTC1XyIMz///87aBjqGOmYaAIA)

Takes input `$n` then uses a `Where-Object` to pull out those elements that are `-g`reaterthanor`e`qual to `2` times the `$l`ast element. Those are left on the pipeline, and we set our `$l`ast element for the next iteration. We then take the `.count` of that collection and make sure it's `-eq`ual to the `.count` of our input array. That Boolean value is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

---

If we don't need to worry about negative numbers, we can use the following instead, thanks to mazzy:

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 27 bytes

```powershell
!($args|?{$_-lt2*$l;$l=$_})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1FDJbEovbjGvlolXjenxEhLJcdaJcdWJb5W8////4b/jf6bAAA)

This again takes input `$args`, and pulls out those items where they're `-l`ess`t`han `2` times the `$l`ast element (i.e., they're not "big enough" to make the doubling sequence). If there are any left, then the Boolean-not surrounding the collection results in `False`, otherwise if the collection is empty we get `True`. That's left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
[:*/0.5>:2%/\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o6209A30TO2sjFT1Y2L/a3IpcKUmZ@QrpCkYGigYGSgYG6DyTRB8BSMFY2SOCTLHEEmdIZIRhv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 11 bytes

```
49          DEC  CX                 ; adjust to loop N-1 times
        N_LOOP:
AD          LODSW                   ; load N1 into AX 
D1 E0       SHL  AX, 1              ; double AX 
39 04       CMP  WORD PTR[SI], AX   ; compare to N2
7C 02       JL   DONE               ; if less, return
E2 F7       LOOP N_LOOP             ; keep looping 
        DONE:
C3          RET                     ; return to caller
```

Input array at `[SI]`, length in `CX`.  Returns `ZF` if `truthy`, `NZ` if `falsey`.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 28 bytes

GolfScript has its clunky zip function (I need a lot of code to convert the string to a list of codepoints).

```
.1>]zip);{1/~0=\0=2*<!}%{&}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbWigYGSgYGwQ@1/P0C62KrNA07raUL/OwDbGwNZIy0axVrVarVbrf2zCfwA)

## Explanation

```
.1>]zip                      # Zip itself with itself without the first item
       );                    # Discard the extra trailing item
         {1/~0=\0=2*<!}%     # Is the first item * 2 greater than or equal to the next item?
                        {&}* # All of them?
```

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 31 bytes

```
.(+{2/}%]zip);{1/{0=}%~>!}%{&}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbahgpGBoEPtfT0O72ki/VjW2KrNA07raUL/awLZWtc5OsVa1Wq1W639swn8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
<1hS/MP.T,t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38YwI1jfN0AvRKfk//9oQx1jHTMdQxMdY2MdQwMDHRMDo1gA)

#### Explanation

```
<1hS/MP.T,tQQ  # full program, last two Q (=input) are implicit

         ,tQQ  # [Q[1:], Q]
       .T      # Transpose -> [[Q[1],Q[0]], [Q[2],Q[1]], ...,  [Q[-1]]]
      P        # all but last element (gets rid of lone Q[-1])
    /M         # Map all pairs by division
   S           # Sort quotients
  h            # first element (minimum quotient)
<1             # is 1 smaller than this?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 15 bytes

```
raJ0{2.*>=}LO==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/2/KNHLoNpIT8vOttbH39b2f21u9P9oQwMdIwMdY4NYLijTBMzUMdIxhtImUNoQImEIUWkYCwA)

Finally got an answer where using `LO` is advantageous.

```
ra   # Read as array
J    # Duplicate
0    # 0 (start of loop)
{2.* # Double
 >=  # Greater than or equal to previous elem
}LO  # Loop through array performing op on each pair
     # Push to array if true
==   # Arrays are the same
```

## Burlesque, 16 bytes

Alternative (but longer) solutions using 2-grams and map-reduce

```
ra2CO{./2>=}m^r&
ra2CO{p^./2>=}al
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/2/KNHI2b9aT9/IzrY2N65I7X9tbvT/aEMDHSMDHWODWC4o0wTM1DHSMYbSJlDaECJhCFFpGAsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>25</s> 15 bytes

```
Min@Ratios@#<2&
```

Returns `True` for false and `False` for true.

-10 bytes thanks to @att

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@983M88hCMjNL3ZQtjFS@x9QlJlXEq2soGun4BatHBuroKag76BQXW1ooKNgBMTGBrU6CnCeCYQH5ABlEEwTBNMQpsIQps@wtvY/AA)

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@983M88hCMjNL3ZQtjFS@x9QlJlXEq2soGun4BatHBuroKag76BQXW1ooKNgBMTGBrU6CnCeCYQH5ABlEEwTBNMQpsIQps@wtvY/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-r`, 11 bytes

```
$&2*_<=BMPg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRc1IK97G1sk3IP3/f0MDLiMDLmOD/7pFAA)

Takes input numbers separater by newlines. (`-r` flag)

### Explanation

```
$&2*_<=BMPg  g → input
        MP   pass pairs from g to function on the left
  2*_<=B     a ≤ b? for pair (a, b)
$&           Fold with & operator
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 41 bytes

```
a=>all([a[x+1]/a[x]>=2for x:0..len(a)-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/R1i4xJ0cjOjG6QtswVh9IxdrZGqXlFylUWBno6eWk5mkkauoaxmr@LyjKzCvRSNOINtRRMNJRMNVRMASxjGI1Nf8DAA)

This isn't very efficient because Proton is too buggy to do this right.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
$=>[l:0every?&'x[x>=l*2l:x]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?FlfhwT)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
↔ʁ/2≥Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UduUU436Ro86l55b8P9/tLGOmY6haSwA)

Outputs 1 if doubling array, 0 otherwise

```
↔           implicit input; flip array
 ʁ/         ʁeduce by division
   2≥       is each element greater than or equal to 2?
     Π      take product of list; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 27 bytes

```
rl1)?v1n;n0<
@:$+:<|.!:0^?)
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoicmwxKT92MW47bjA8XG5AOiQrOjx8LiE6MF4/KSIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiIxIDIgNCA4IDEwMCIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

- `r` reverse
- `l1)?` is the length greater than 1?
- `v` then go down
- `1n;` otherwise, output 1 (true)
- `<` go left
- `:+` double
- `$:@` duplicate NOS
- `)?` is NOS greater than TOS?
- `^<0n;` then output 0 (false)
- `0:!.|` go back to start after inverting direction

Answer (score 1):

## [StackCell](https://github.com/Starwort/StackCell), 16 bytes

`:[{::+}x>?.:]'Y;`

- Assumes that the input list is already present on the stack (with the earliest element on the *bottom* of the stack, as it would be as a result of repeated pushing), and does not contain a 0 (will be interpreted as end of input) - [For stack-based languages, function's input may be pushed to the stack before calling](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/84094)

  - To run the program, prepend the input in hex, with hashes, e.g. `#01#02#04:[{::+}x>?.:]'Y;` to run the program on `[1, 2, 4]`
- Either prints `Y` (the input is a doubling sequence) or terminates without output (the input is not a doubling sequence) - [Programs and functions may return a boolean value via the presence or absence of output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17938/84094)

Explanation:

- `:[`: Duplicate the top element of the stack, and then consume the duplicate. If it was non-zero, perform the loop body (up until the next `]`) - else skip the loop body
- `{`: Remove the top element of the stack, and place it in the 'cell' (temporary storage which is overwritten on writes and copied on reads)
- `::+`: Create two duplicates of the top element of the stack (previously the top-but-one element), and add them together to get 2x
- `}`: Put the stored element back on the top of the stack
- `x`: Swap the top two elements of the stack
- `>`: Consume and compare the top two elements of the stack: If the top-most element is larger than the second-most element of the stack, push `1` to the stack, otherwise push `0` to the stack
- `?`: Consume the value on top of the stack, and skip the next instruction (`.`) if and only if the consumed value was 0
- `.`: Halt the program immediately (falsy output)
- `:]`: Duplicate the top value of the stack, then consume the duplicate. If it was non-zero, jump back to the instruction after the matching `[`; otherwise, continue
- `'Y`: Push the character `Y` to the stack, as a byte
- `;`: Print the top value of the stack, as a character

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
∆$i≥
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FisedbSpZD7qXLqkOCm5GCq44KZ1tKGBjpGBjrFBLBeUaQJm6hjpGENpEyhtCJEwhKg0jIWYAQA)

```
-e      Check that
∆       the delta
   ≥    is greater than or equal to
 $i     the original list without the last item
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 38 bytes

Returns 0 for doubling sequences, 1 otherwise.

```c
f(*a,s){return--s?*a*2>*++a|f(a,s):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNb4QgEIbP8ismNJuAH43aPa1b99Zf0JvxQPxoTSwSwF6sv90OuJcmdQ/MwDzzDvA2STMK@bFtPQtFbPiiOztrmSTmFoowL8MoEj89c@iSFuv2NMhmnNsOrsa2w/T8WRIySEu@xCDZ9zS0nCwkwAo0MciCBMbqubEwSDVbQORZKLQu7vuxc20rYKmq4dX3LMAcqmq@QJbGkON6SWHFiOGg4XzYgHwHx/T8kGYPRmcO5f8/6w9zEY@hKggJ@kkzhb91RoBKSp@jSHH//x7NMoxWNAa0eZotd245jURNWoCEq1M571AlOdJAaby7Z/RkTi0KJdwAE4ULUMz7HZWs/Sg/v2d7Mb6P4k5RQ1LCmxhN55X@@K7njjrdStbtFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 48 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://_.sliding(2).map%7Bcase%20Seq(a,b)=%3Eb/a%7D.exists(_%3C2))

```scala
_.sliding(2).map{case Seq(a,b)=>b/a}.exists(_<2)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBbsIwDL33K94xkaqOdpyqgTTEEU5oJzQht01RppCiJpuKUL@9c4PgAvXBtt7L84vtSjI0DE3xo0qPLWmLaxQBlapRiy7HRju/Xze/hVHfMseqaYwiiwU/A0eXOKMrbY8ik8mJzriiJKeCTFCMQmKxRIE3EPpEdQw7ccAHMsn6/m51YmNB7dHl@Gxbuux3vuWho@OX1f5h90cGFXliIDgEELc@nSWzGFnI75xlPMXOn9lABuU0NZ@m0tcT09e/GOGAyiiUM@/qjRXjZuMRRS1v1@mH4R8)

```scala
object Main {

  def f(x: List[Double]): Boolean = {
    x.sliding(2).map { case List(a, b) => b / a }.exists(_ < 2)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val data = List(
      List(10.0, 20.0, 30.0),
      List(10.0, 20.0, 40.0),
      List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0),
      List(1.0, 2.0, 4.0),
      List(1.0, 2.0, 10.0),
      List(1.0, 1.0),
      List(10.0, 1.0)
    )

    println(data.map(f))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 27 bytes

```
f(l)=\{l[2...]<2l,0\}.\max
```

Returns `0` for doubling sequences and `1` for non-doubling sequences.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bvtk5hg9po)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lafwfm6l1g)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 3 bytes

```
¯>Ṫ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJHIiwiIiwiwq8+4bmqIiwiIiwiWzEwLDIwLDQwXSJd)

A port of 05AB1E

### Explained

```
¯>Ṫ
¯   # deltas
 >  # greater than original input
  Ṫ # last item removed
# G flag gets biggest item.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 50 bytes

```
{a:IntArray->(0..a.size-2).first{a[it]*2>a[it+1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxbsMgEIbn8hQnlAEaG9lOJke11CGVunRJtsgDsnBC40CEsdUU8ewuRO3S@KQ7dB//cfo5a9tJNbWDgguXilBw6GnkHbTwApPj5buyr8bwW1qRjDHOevkt0oKyVpreOn6Qtn4uqngu89r7CUK07GqksiTPEihCrjKK5vj6Pw84qOfgeg7mj/P546aAPELRISF/biikFYSG/upGbrg5Qsi@vPPg/n7TKYIXLnL2qaXa650N@EhwghPAh1hqTH18buGsuYEDqUZ9FiTO0A3gN971AoOHhtvmBESU8KF3Q3PaduIilN1@NeJqpVbh6wHvzRDFHlM0/QA)

`Int` for false and `Nothing` for true (throws `NoSuchElementException`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
\d+
$*
((^|,(?=\3\3))(1+))+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0tDI65GR8PeNsY4xlhTU8NQW1NTW@X/f0MDHSMDHWMDLgjDBMjQMdIxBpMmYNIQJGQIkjcEAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
  ^|
```

On the first repeat, match at the beginning, otherwise...

```
    ,(?=\3\3)
```

... match a comma followed by a number which is at least twice as big as the previous match.

```
              (1+)
```

Capture the number so that it can be compared on the next repeat.

```
(                 )+$
```

All entries in the list need to satisfy the above conditions.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 89 bytes

```clj
(fn[x](#(cond(empty? %)true(>=(first %)(* %2 2))(recur(rest %)(first %)):else false)x 0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtBCsIwEEX3PcWAFGZcJWlXgnqQ0oWkE6jEtEwTqKePAdFm83lv5n/rl2cSzjixA5fRhWEf8YR2CRPya43vO7QUJTHeruhm2WJxPENrwBChsE1S8nv@/enCfmNwj5K0gyLK1OAqc4g@NOhg0AqMgk6NVGn/VzDQVdxXrI@SPtYFqckf)

The obvious (and longest) solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-apl -MList::Util=reduce`, 26 bytes

```perl
reduce{$_&&=$a<=$b/2;$b}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/78oNaU0ObVaJV5NzVYl0cZWJUnfyFolqdbB7f9/QwMFIwMFY4N/@QUlmfl5xf91Ewty/uv6@mQWl1hZhZZk5thCtAMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda l:all(2*l[i]<=l[i+1]for i in range(len(l)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBDoIwEEX3PcXfWRQTKq6MuPQE7pA0JRRtMhRSYeHpsYhRTOAn7SR9nZk/0zzbe23jvtAlFKfgwOBV1g4GxsIpe9OctPVoKz50kCmxW1NqMpzgw0ZkPzbI6bZzFmdFD80mDxfXacZyJNeeVJUXCnRQRHwsdkzGWkv9g7fPShnLJ05p@JmmIgqx8yeOsvDPC/Bl@znmkc9aAvslIOZrifnuIptsqHHGtpzC98pD5P4OGPM7ldKqSkuJJMFKymFSKVdj4jh2/wI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 29 bytes

```sh
(($1*2<=$2))&&${=3+$0 ${@:2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCoMwFET39ysGuWjSbvJwZRvor5SSEKFU0HTT4LenWq2rM8MZ5jPFEoQURQjWJ3N1bKSsa87OnlmB860z81wkURhGJD8lCGq0glGwqvnH9hdhYHe2O/Um9LZcIJGJ@oAAduvdBSn6FwH@EQdUaXx7dOBVVeSfkz9UuC/tUKEnmssX)

```sh
(($1*2<=$2))&&     # return false if 2 * $1 > $2
  ${=3+$0 ${@:2}}  # recursive call:
  ${ 3+         }  # if there is a third parameter
       $0 ${@:2}   # ... substitute the program name ($0), " ", "$2 $3 $4 "...
  ${=           }  # ... then split on spaces
```

In cases like `a &&` or `b ||`, Zsh will simply return with the exit code of the previous command.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda l:all(l[i-1]*2<=l[i]for i in range(1,len(l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjEnRyMnOlPXMFbLyMYWyIpNyy9SyFTIzFMoSsxLT9Uw1MlJzdPI0dTU/P//f2JxcWpRiUKaRrShgY6RgY6xQaymQmaxgltiTnEqF7qsCVQ2pKgURVLHSMcYhz6glAlOTYa4zDPE6QpkGQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 18 bytes

```apl
∧/{(2×¯1↓⍵)≤(1↓⍵)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HHcv1qDaPD0w@tN3zUNvlR71bNR51LNGDs2v/Vj/qmPmqboPGotw/I8vR/1NV8aL3xo7aJQF5wkDOQDPHwDNYE0rWPehdXGwDJNf8NDRSMDBSMDbggDBMgQ8FIwRhMmoBJQ5CQIUjeEAA)

Decomposition/Explanation:

```apl
⍵ is the input vector (test cases). Output will be 1 or 0; 1 is TRUE/truthy, 0 is FALSE/falsey.

            (1↓⍵)  - Drop the first element from the input vector (call it LASTN)
      ¯1↓⍵         - Drop the last element from the input vector, separately, and
   (2×    )        - multiply it by two (call the result DFIRSTN)
           ≤       - compare corresponding elements - Each element of LASTN should be 
                     equal to or greater than the corresponding element of DFIRSTN.
  {              } - encapsulate as a dfn to apply to the input vector. This dfn will
                     return 0 for elements where the comparison is FALSE, 1 where TRUE
∧/                 - AND (Boolean conjunction) reduction of the vector. ∧/ A B C D ... is
                     equivalent to A ∧ B ∧ C ∧ D ∧ ..., and if there are any FALSE values
                     in the vector, the result will be FALSE (0)
```

The linked TIO has the test cases and a REPL; you can test your own vectors by changing the input field, one vector per line.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
r;f(a,l)int*a;{for(r=--l;l--;)r=*a*2>*++a?0:r;a=r;}
```

Pretty simple. For every element of the array, check if the current element times two is greater than the next element.

Returns zero if it is not a doubling sequence and non-zero (or more specifically the length minus one) otherwise.

*-10 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLBboMwDIbveQoLqRIBskHXU7O0tz3BbohDRGFCYqEysMMQz84cGIz2UBYpcRL//pLYScVHmg4DytzVQckL03hadnmFLiohSlkKITkqT3v7k@f7@hweUWqFsh/qBtu0gcJc24Z1DKhROHgaUS6rMjOS9ZIxu/jUhXG/quLCf/VrBFBcnIAaHZN7nIFrQ@OEdxCFAeypv4TQ00jDQ9lhQ0aqyb2lOfxDE20eFlnB/tGlbxU2a9baYoy5TEFBKMm8Ql18ZxWVDJE//83jMOHk933gd1m8IgFy14nB4XLZXchmIhsiW0yaPNm6gVlI95zdZVeDE8xqa0wSWI5aEUDQk87gOHAk8frkmZOAON1ciT5C7U6PmbjBisct7B3bbAS@6bLO5tie9cMP)

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks. I was trying to find a solution with no counter variable.

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZLBboQgEIbvPMXEZDeg0qrdU1naW5@gN@OBsNqYWNyg9lDjs9tBq3X3sFsSGGD@@YAZNP/QehytKKgKK1aa1leiL2pLRcwrzvd7aqWv/OQo/SBQTDChpBXD2LS20y2U5ty1pCeADYPBV9aKdVXlRpBBEOIWn6o09KsuT@xXv0UAxqUZyMkxu6cZUBeaZqyHOAohwf4UwYAjDjdlhzsyVM3ue5rDPzTx3cNiJ0huXfpS4bLmrCvFlEsNEiKB5ghN@Z3XWDBr2ePfPI0yhv4gAHaVxbNFQEG9FDwm1t2VbGayQbLD6OzB1Q3MSrrm7E67BrxwUTtjstBx5IYAHJ/0Cp4HzyjenrxwMuAvF1fCj9DQ@TEzN9zwmIO92y6fgG@qavIldiDD@AM "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [<strike>75</strike>](https://null.link.io) [<strike>71</strike>](https://null.link.io) [<strike>67</strike>](https://null.link.io) 65 bytes

```cpp
int f(int*a,int s){int r=1;for(;--s;)r*=a[s]>=2*a[s-1];return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZNdb4IwFIavx684yS4Eg7NfKFhlP8Rx0SAuJLOYUi82w293p9qYublKCOWU53l7@Kr3@8l7XZ@eW11/HDYNLNuut6ZRu/LUagvbGI9jlbrzPjm6wayo3HYmlpNJLxMzXql1X5UrNsZxQitpGnswGowcTrbZ7T@Udako6jLC6ENtQRmjPuEYAbh5rNa6kr7q268mTuDoY7Qc/IVu3xhlO7OuXE/QJucAAA/GGkpoQekNHssVkOT1nNxWsADi0odokFHk3J1qUbgEnHtZFiUoEsORpsBSyFKgBM@wEljmrp7jBBd0SCTAdAr0qnJUqVOd4SAygIPub6iSG5X9UMUj9XZVfm2Yh7x7q4qrKh6rt6tmV5WSsHujMlRnF5U@WPJ3w06d@8f02P1zrzmqjOf4HgvGsXFB8n9C/qgFqkUuMubejyh4dh4FF9nvBH@vuPd2s1jU3cHCcon/jyIvmJfi5/Vy@bQTNz9606PoyYkXiHqIhiDmIRaCuId4CBIeEiEo81AWgmYemoWguYfmISj3UB6CCg8V9yEZDadv)

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks for the input! I thought the `i++` placement was [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior_2), so I dumped the variable - 67 bytes!

Comment: @ceilingcat Should've thought of that!

Comment: [64](https://tio.run/##hZPdToMwFICv5SmO8UIwTPvHBivDB5lcNAwNiStL6S508uzzdGsWN7UjhPaU7zs9paXZbCZvTbO/63Tzvl21ZdcP1rRqXe07beE1xueDSl1/SHauMQsiX3sTy8lkkIn5WqjlUJfsAZsJraVp7dboWyPHvW3Xm3dlWyidp6sIM28bC8oY9QG7CMCNY7TUtfTR0H22cQK7YxrQcvQv@k1rlO3NsnYlQZccEgB4MNZQQQdKr/BZLYAkz4fMXQ1zIC77GI0yitaq03Hi1EMVZVGBIjHsaAoshSwFSrCHkcAwd/EMB7igYyIBnp6AnlSOKnWqMxxERnDQ3xeq5ExlP1RxTT2flZ8K5iHvr1nFSRXX1fNZs5NKSdg9Uxmq06NKr0x5WbBTZ/4zXXd/rTVHlfEc97FgHAsXJP8nyS@1QLXIRcbc/oiCZ4dWcJFdZvBrxXuwq/m86bcWyhJ/HEUeMV@Kx@vxeKgTN37/ou@jGyceIeohGoKYh1gI4h7iIUh4SISgzENZCJp6aBqCZh6ahaDcQ3kIKjxUXEIyGvff "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 64 bytes

This can handle positive values above 0

Returns -1 for true, 0 for false

```sql
SELECT~min(1/~x)FROM(SELECT a/lag(2*a)over(ORDER BY i)x FROM @)y
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/BOPAD30889)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>101</s> 100 bytes

```
listen to F
D's0
while F
listen to T
let R be F/T-.5
turn up R
let D be D or R
let F be T

say not D
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in, with each input integer on an individual line)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S!`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṣ$ṫ<
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBMiUyNCVFMSVCOSVBQiUzQyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU1QjEwJTJDMjAlMkMzMCU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAwJTBBJTVCMTAlMkMyMCUyQzQwJTVEJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElNUIxJTJDMiUyQzMlNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwMCUwQSU1QjElMkMyJTJDNCU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAxJTBBJTVCMSUyQzIlMkMxMCU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAxJTBBJTVCMSUyQzElNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwMCUwQSU1QjEwJTJDMSU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAwJmZsYWdzPUNTIQ==) Link is to verify all test cases.

##### Explanation

```python
Ṣ$ṫ<  # Implicit input
Ṣ     # Deltas of input
 $ṫ   # Input without last item
   <  # Compare the two lists
      # Check if the sum is 0
      # Implicit output
```